# How to use alert to confirm or cancel view transition?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

On certain conditions, if users intent to leave the current view (e.g. pop the current view, push other view, or select other tab items etc.), a UIAlertController should be presented to confirm users' real intention.

Users can press OK to proceed the view transitioning, or Cancel to stay on the current view.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    if someConditions {
        promptUIAlert()
    }
}
```

Any solutions that can achieve that requirements?

Comment: when user press back button, show your `promptUIAlert ` and onclick of `ok` make user to leave that view simple

Comment: you can use delegates for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you **cannot** handle this is `viewWillDisappear` because at this point it has already been decided that the view *will disappear*. You need to handle this wherever you have view transitions (push, pop, present, dismiss).

You have to handle the transitions in the confirmation alert action. You alert would look something like this.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Wait!", message: "Are you sure you want to leave this view?", preferredStyle: .alert)
let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (alertAction) in
    //Handle view transitioning here
}
let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive) { (alertAction) in
    //Do nothing?
}
alert.addAction(ok)
alert.addAction(cancel)
present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Since users might leave the current view on several ways, e.g. push a view, pop a view, or selecting other tabs, I was thinking about a more convenient solution to the problem.

Comment: @HamkuuShaw Well, you wrote the code for leaving the view. So you have to change the code to make it leave from the alert action instead at every single place. There is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

You can't intercept and retain the user in the same `ViewController` once the `viewWillDissaper` is fired. You should do it in advance. My suggestion is to add a `UIBarButton` with a label Back to the `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` and manually check whether the user wants to navigate or not. This is the closest you can get.

also, you can use the `UIAlertViewController` to confirm whether the user wants to navigate or not.

```
    //inside viewDidLoad
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleBack))

    //define another function to handle the selctor
    @objc func handleCancel(){
       if someConditions {
                promptUIAlert()
        }
    }

    //you function should be like this with UIAlertController
    func promptUIAlert(){
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Some message", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let CancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default) { (action) in
         //type your custom code here for cancel action
        }
let OkAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action) in
         //type your custom code here for OK action
        }
        alertController.addAction(OKAction)
        alertController.addAction(CancelAction)

        self.present(alertController, animated: true)
    }
```

Doing something inside `viewWillDissaper` would be handy to save some unsaved data behind the screen. But not to prompt and ask the user whether they want to remain in the same ViewController.